# WPF TabControl Animation,How can I move the background from the active tabItem to the tabItem where the mouse ls over

Tags: wpf, animation, background

Actually this question is different from many similar ones about TabControl animation. I failed to get a helpful solution among them.

Scene1: TabItem1 is the selected TabItem with blue background, followed by tabItem2 and tabItem3 with white background. Now I move the mouse over tabItem3. I want an animation to "move" the blue background from tabItem1 to tabItem3 across tabItem2, which means during the animation there are frames where tabItem2 has blue background.

Scene2:After scene1 I move the mouse out, the blue background rushes back to the selected TabItem

Many webpages use this effect on the menu bar, like this site
http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/

Notice the blue line above the menu item.It is definitely the animation that I want.Is it possible in WPF?

Comment: Yes that is easy to achieve, what u have tried ?

Comment: Sorry I am really a starter in wpf with only days of xaml experience.I don't think it can be achieved only by xaml. I tried to divide the whole animation to several parts. In back code, I would repeatedly run an animation to move the background to the next TabItem until the background reach the target TabItem. I tried to use ColorAnimation to implement this animation unit but stopped by how to write the animation for two TabItems. And I doubt it is too complicated because in flash we can achieve this using mask layer.

Comment: If your Tabs are fixed in number, then you can assign x:Name to each and do everything in xaml itself.